# Access IP Camera with static IP and port in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am new to Python and learning...

I am trying to access IP Camera which is not in my network. This IP Camera is configured via Static IP and Port that I can access via browser. To access in browser I need to use following:

1. URL - http://:
2. Login screen appears where I enter User ID and Password

Question is, how to access such remote IP camera bypassing login screen in python? What could be the URL format? Any specific library should I use?

What is working:
If my IP camera is in my network, I can use below URL and it works fine.

`webcam = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://<userid>:<password>@<IP Address of IP Camera in my network>")`